# How to add just certain modules in article page(Joomla 1.5)

Tags: php, joomla

I am new to Joomla and doing theme customization on localhost.Now every thing is working fine .But i don't Know that if there is menu link which associated with a article.When i click on that i want that leftpanel of my index.php page and some other modules do not display at the time of that aricle is displaying on the screen.How to do that to remove certain modules at the time of pariculer aricle is displaying on the page.Please give me a step by step decsription for  this problem as i am new to joomla.

Thanks in advance!!!!!

Comment: In the Module Manager, when editing a module, you can select which pages the module is to be shown on, simply deselect the articles (menu items) or select just the homepage.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are talking about only displaying a module on certain articles that do not have a menu item to control the display with, one solution would be to add in an assertion to your template in a new module position, something like:

```
<?php
$articleId = Number of article from a query or set as static value....
if(JRequest::getVar('option') == 'com_content' && JRequest::getVar('id') == $articleId)
{
?>
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="slideshow" style="xhtml"/>
<?php
}
?>
```

That is how you would do it if the module position is outside of the content area, alternatively if you want to display a module inside an article you could use {loadposition myModulePosition}, just make sure the module is set to display on all pages (dont worry it wont due to the conditional).

Comment: You should never hard code anything like this in to the template, it's not the place for it. Changing/adding/or removing articles from the list would require a code change. Everything specified can be done within the Joomla framework with menu items and extensions without having to hard code anything in to the template.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_assign_a_module_to_specific_pages%3F

If you need to assign modules to more complex situations, use:

http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/advancedmodulemanager

Answer (score 0):

Go to that particular module from "module manager" from joomla admin manager. Then uncheck it's visibility from particular menu which u had created. If u keep it display on all page it show that module on all menu items which u had create. Check only that menu on which you want to display that module.